# Creating the same, double applications for iOS permitted?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

To get more exposure in the App Store for iOS apps I found out that creating a second application for 'top keywords' is vital for getting more downloads. I am considering creating 4 or 5 iOS applications that are identical to each other (in code) with a completely different design on a top search keyword.

To give an example, let's say I've created an iPhone game with the name "Pokemon Center". To get more exposure on the popular search term "Pokemon game" I simply create 4 other games with exactly the same content in a very different design. "Pokemon Center for Kids", "Pokemon Center Fast Play", "Pokemon Center Red" etc.

An better example: "2048 original", "2048 lite", "2048 for Kids", "2048 for Adults"

So far, it worked as I have 2 identical applications in the App Store. And I'm getting more downloads & revenue. My games (or game) is actually getting really positive reviews from players.

Is this permitted?

Comment: Sounds like what a scammer would do - so really does not impress me. As for Pokemon surely this is a trade mark and I doubt you own it so really looks like a scam.

Comment: I probably need to explain better - My game is not about Pokemon or any other trademarked name, it was an example. I guess you might be right that it's the same as spamming. But as long as users appreciate my application I think it's not that bad.

Comment: I'm going to edit out the "what's your opinion" and ask you to solidify what problem you are trying to solve here. If you want to know if it's against the rules - go ahead and ask that. If you want to know something else - please try to steer this away from "I feel this way about XYZ - what do others think?" territory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple can reject apps which are duplicates:

> **2.11**
>   Apps that duplicate Apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra Apps

<sup>Source: Apple App Store Review Guidelines</sup>

You should only create one app and spend your efforts promoting this app. Furthermore, if you seek to make apps that appeal to users with clear functionality, Apple's interests and your interests will align. In the case where you are looking to ride hot search terms, unless your apps are really what you are seeding in the search terms - trying to work the system shouldn't work in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Apple will revoke apps in the AppStore containing the same information and code. You have to make individual projects with more differences or change the design after login for example.

Please check [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_app_approvals)

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure each application contains different functionalities. By using different designs I'm targeting different age groups.